# When does almost everywhere convergence imply convergence in measure?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a finite measure space. Is it true that

If every subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ has a subsequence which converge to $f$ almost everywhere, then  $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure?

I have proved the converse of this statement, but problem says it is if and only if statement. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What goes wrong when the measure space is not finite? Why does the finiteness help against this problem?

Comment: Actually I used finiteness part for the converse so that i could apply Borel Cantelli(to use continuty from above), but for this statment I am not really sure. As far as I know, $L^p$ domination will be enough to conclude the proof, yet we have only finitness of measure which does not imply that f is in $L^p$ for some $p$

Comment: @AntonioMontana According to [Proof Wiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Pointwise_Convergence_Implies_Convergence_in_Measure), finiteness is not needed

Comment: @ AlexR Finiteness is definitely needed, proof-wiki gave false statement: consider $f_n=\chi_{(n,n+1)}$, then $f_n$ goes to zero a.e, but not in measure

Comment: In Cohn's Measure Theory, Proposition 3.1.2, the converse is proven without assuming the measure is finite.

Comment: @AlexR I'm viewing that page right now you linked, they didn't wrote a proof, the "prof" section it's empty

Comment: @Santropedro Did you check out the mentioned book? Probably there is a proof in there at the quoted position.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can show the contrapositive.

Assume that $f_n$ doesn't converge to $f$ in measure. This means that there is $\delta\gt 0$, an $\varepsilon\gt 0$ and a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ such that for each $k$, 
$$\mu\{|f_{n_k}-f|\gt \varepsilon\}\gt \delta.$$

If $(f_{m_k})_k$ is a subsequence of $(f_{n_k})_k$, we have to show that $f_{m_k}$ doesn't converge almost everywhere to $f$. Define $A_k:=\{|f_{m_k}-f|\gt \varepsilon\}$. Then we have, *using finiteness of the measure space*, 
$$\mu\left(\limsup_{k\to \infty}A_k\right)=\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k\geqslant j}A_k\right)\geqslant \delta.$$

Comment: How did we use the finiteness of the measure space?

Answer (score 8):

This is an easy corollary from [Egorov's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem), which states:

> Given some measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ Let $f_n: E\rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on some $E \in
>  \Sigma, \mu(E)<\infty$. Where $f_n \rightarrow f^*$ pointwise for some $f^*: E \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}$. Then for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a set
>   $F_\epsilon \in \Sigma, F_\epsilon \subset E$ such that
>   $\mu(F_\epsilon) < \epsilon$ and $f_n \rightarrow f^*$
>   uniformly on $E\backslash F_\epsilon$.

Can you deduce the theorem from Egorov on your own?