# If a sequence converges in measure, are convergent subsequences of it all converge to the same limit?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $f_n:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of measurable functions such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure.

Let $f_{n_k}$ be a subsequence of $f_n$ such that $f_{n_k}\rightarrow g$ pointwise a.e.. Then, is it necessary that $f=g$ a.e.?What would be a counterexample?

Comment: Don't you have convergence a.e. implies convergence in measure, so that the subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ converges to $g$ in measure. Since $(f_{n_k})_k$ also converges to $f$ in measure, [then](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/42137/75808) $f=g$ a.e.? (I'm rusty on this, take it with a grain of salt.)

Comment: Why does convervence a.e. imply convergence in measure?

Comment: Ah, yes. It's true if the measure is finite. I assume it's not the case for you?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I'm talking about the general case. However, I'm curious why it holds for the finite case. Do you prove it by applying Egorov's theorem?

Comment: You can have a look [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580334/when-does-almost-everywhere-convergence-imply-convergence-in-measure) for the finite-measure case (I sort of recall it being a consequence of Fatou's lemma, but right now I don't remember much.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question:

> Let $f_n:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of measurable functions such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure.
>
> Let $f_{n_k}$ be a subsequence of $f_n$ such that $f_{n_k}\rightarrow g$ pointwise a.e.. Then, is it necessary that $f=g$ a.e.?What would be a counterexample?

The answer is YES. It is true that $f=g\:$ a.e..

First, note that a standard result in Measure Theory says:

> If $f_n:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a sequence of measurable functions such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, then there is  $f_{n_k}$, a subsequence of $f_n$, such that $f_{n_k}\rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e..

(See, for instance, Royden's *Real Analysis*, fourth edition, section 5.2, page 100, Theorem 4)

In your question:

Since $f_n$ converges in measure to $f$ and $f_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of ${f_n}$, we have that $f_{n_k}$ also converges in measure to $f$, and so, by the abovementioned result, there is a subsequence $f_{n_{k_j}} $ of  $f_{n_k}$ which converges to $f$ pointwise a.e. .

Since  $f_{n_k}$  converges to $g$ pointwise a.e. and
$f_{n_{k_j}} $ is a subsequence of $f_{n_k}$, we have that $f_{n_{k_j}} $ also converges  to $g$ pointwise a.e. to $g$.

So, $f_{n_{k_j}}$ converges to $f$ pointwise a.e.  and  $f_{n_{k_j}} $ also converges  to $g$ pointwise a.e.. So $f=g\:$ a.e..

Comment: Very nice! ${}{}$