# Understanding why almost everywhere pointwise convergeence implies convergence in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In the top answer given to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580334/when-does-almost-everywhere-convergence-imply-convergence-in-measure), the conclusion is that $$\mu\Big(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k\geq j}A_k\Big)\geq \delta$$
But I don't understand why this implies that it doesn't converge pointwise. I was under the impression that we had to conclude $\lim f_i(x)\neq f(x)$.
Can someone clear this up?

Answer (score 0):

This answer merely expounds upon angryavian's answer to answer D. Brio's question in the comments.

Suppose $x\in \bigcap_{j=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=j}^\infty A_k$.

Then for any positive integer $N$, $\,x\in \bigcap_{j=N}^\infty \bigcup_{k=j}^\infty A_k$.

But then $x\in A_k$ for some $k\geq N$.

And that implies $x\in \{z | f_{m_k}(z) −f(z)|>\epsilon\}$ for some $k\geq N$.

Hence, $|f_{m_k}(x)-f(x)| > \epsilon$ for some $k\geq N$.

We have shown that for every positive integer $N$, there exists a $k\geq N$ such that $|f_{m_k}(x)-f(x)| > \epsilon$.  So the $f_{m_k}(x)$ do not converge pointwise to $f(x)$ for any $x\in \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=j}^\infty A_k$.