# If for a.e. $x \in X$ the sequence $(f_n(x, \cdot))_n$ is Cauchy in $L^0 (Y)$, then $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $L^0 (Z)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ be *complete finite* measure spaces,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $Z := X \times Y$,
- $\mathcal C$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$,
- $\lambda$ the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$,
- $(Z, \overline{\mathcal C}, \overline{\lambda})$ the completion of $(Z, \mathcal C, \lambda)$.

For $\delta >0$ and $f,g \in L^0 (Y)$, we write
$$
\begin{align*}
\{|f - g| > \delta\} &:= \{y \in Y : |f (y) - g(y)| > \delta\}, \\
\nu (|f - g| > \delta) &:= \nu (\{|f - g| > \delta\}).
\end{align*}
$$

For $f, g \in L^0 (Y)$, we define
$$
\hat \rho_Y (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \nu (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}.
$$

Then $\hat \rho_Y$ is an [extended pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Metric_space#Generalizations_of_metric_spaces) on $L^0 (Y)$. For $f_n, f \in L^0(Y)$, we have $\hat \rho_Y (f_n, f) \to 0$ [IFF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754273/convergence-in-a-complete-measure-is-metrizable) $f_n \to f$ [in measure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions). We define $\hat \rho_X$ on $L^0(X, \mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\})$ and $\hat \rho_Z$ on $L^0(Z)$ similarly. For simplicity, we write
$$
\begin{align*}
\| f \|_{L^0(X)} & := \hat \rho_X (f, 0), \\
\| f \|_{L^0(Y)} &:= \hat \rho_Y (f, 0), \\
\| f \|_{L^0(Z)} &:= \hat \rho_Z (f, 0).
\end{align*}
$$

I'm trying to prove an analogue of the main result in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756819/if-for-a-e-x-in-x-the-sequence-f-nx-cdot-n-is-cauchy-in-lp-text) thread, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $f_n \in L^0(Z)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Assume that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$, the sequence $(f_n(x, \cdot))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (Y), \hat \rho_Y)$. Then $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (Z), \hat \rho_Z)$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt? Thank you so much for your help!

---

Assume the contrary that $(f_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $L^0 (Z)$. There is $\varepsilon >0$ and two subsequences $\varphi, \psi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that
$$
\hat \rho_Z (f_{\varphi (n)}, f_{\psi (n)}) \ge \varepsilon
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
$$

Then
$$
\lambda (|f_{\varphi (n)} - f_{\psi (n)}| > \delta)  +\delta \ge \varepsilon
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N, \forall \delta >0.
$$

We pick $\delta := \varepsilon/2$ and get
$$
\lambda (|f_{\varphi (n)} - f_{\psi (n)}| > \varepsilon/2)  \ge \varepsilon/2
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
$$

Let $g_n := f_{\varphi (n)} - f_{\psi (n)}$. Then $g_n \in L^0(Z)$. We define
$$
h_n: X \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \| g_n (x, \cdot) \|_{L^0 (Y)}.
$$

It has been [verified](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757566/if-nuy-infty-then-f-x-to-l0y-x-mapsto-fx-cdot-is-mu-meas) that $h_n$ indeed belongs to $L^0 (X)$. By our assumption, $h_n \to 0$ $\mu$-a.e. Because $\mu(X) < \infty$, we [get](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580334/when-does-almost-everywhere-convergence-imply-convergence-in-measure) $h_n \to 0$ in measure.

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757594/if-g-n-l0x-to-0-then-f-n-l0-z-to-0) Let $\mu(X) + \nu (Y) < \infty$. Let $g_n \in L^0(Z)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ such that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ we have $(g_n(x, \cdot))_n \subset L^0  (Y)$. We define
> $$
> h_n: X \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}, x \mapsto \| g_n (x, \cdot) \|_{L^0 (Y)}.
> $$
> If $\| h_n \|_{L^0(X)} \to 0$ then $\| g_n \|_{L^0 (Z)} \to 0$.

By **Lemma 4**, $g_n \to 0$ in measure, which is a contradiction. This completes the proof.